# Website is being targeted by mail bots

Tags: search-engines, web-development, security

have a small website. When I perform a netstat is shows a lot of traffic from .p.mail.

I think this is some kind of mail bot, trying to harvest email addresses from my website. How can I prevent this?

```
tcp        0     64 128.199.152.125:ssh     254.96.96.58.stat:49174 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-7.p.mail:52455 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    crawl-66-249-71-7:39927 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-5.p.mail:48034 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-6.p.mail:38781 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-3.p.mail:49137 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9.mail.ru:46906  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-3.p.mail:49102 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-4.p.mail:60833 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-1.p.mail:58404 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-3.p.mail:38515 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    crawl-66-249-71-9:65419 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-4.p.mail:39761 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-3.p.mail:46664 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-5.p.mail:57961 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-2.p.mail:58029 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-6.p.mail:53075 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9.mail.ru:47363  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-4.p.mail:52394 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9.mail.ru:54476  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9.mail.ru:36110  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-2.p.mail:55155 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-7.p.mail:59306 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-2.p.mail:36667 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-5.p.mail:51968 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-4.p.mail:41478 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-5.p.mail:60032 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-2.p.mail:44335 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-6.p.mail:57922 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-1.p.mail:59718 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-3.p.mail:47470 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-6.p.mail:59941 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-1.p.mail:54604 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9.mail.ru:48307  ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-6.p.mail:47410 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-2.p.mail:52740 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9.mail.ru:48957  ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-6.p.mail:55988 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-6.p.mail:45431 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    crawl-66-249-71-1:54299 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-1.p.mail:44075 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-7.p.mail:51332 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-6.p.mail:40081 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-2.p.mail:47806 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-5.p.mail:40396 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    baiduspider-180-7:53078 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 128.199.152.125:http    fetcher9-1.p.mail:46357 CLOSE_WAIT
```

Comment: How about the answer in this [thread](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61331/how-to-block-entire-ips-of-a-vpn-server-by-ip)? Block the IP and see if it stops or continues from a different IP.

Answer (score 2):

You are okay. Some may argue, but this is not a bad bot. I research these things as part of my research and while I do have a lot of activity from mail.ru, I do not have any bad bot activity doing a quick search.

Mail.ru operates a search engine.

This is a web crawler for their search engine. The page referred to in the agent string is http://go.mail.ru/help/robots which you will have to get your browser to translate. Here is what it says:

> Crawler or spider (spider, crawler, bot) - a program that "walks" on
>   the internet urlam and then downloads them for subsequent indexing.
>   After downloading the document robot analyzes it, determines the type,
>   encoding, language and adds links from the page in place for further
>   obkachki. Periodically, the robot returns to the already previously
>   visited page to check their relevance.
>
> Besides the main robot, which indexes the entire Internet as a whole,
>   there are specialized to separate download images, videos, news, rss,
>   etc. Thus, they can accelerate the penetration of a certain type of
>   documents in the search index.

You can block their user agent. From their page:

> Directive is used to disable the robot download parts of the site or
>   the entire site. The value in this line is a partial URL. Examples:

```
User-agent: Mail.RU_Bot 
Disallow: / # is blocking access to the entire site 

User-agent: Mail.Ru 
Disallow: / search # blocks access to pages starting with '/ search', /search.html, / search / something, etc.
                  # To access other sections of the site open 
User-agent: * 
Disallow: # allowed access to the entire site, 
                  # Is equivalent to the absence of robots.txt
```

You should be able to block the robot from your entire site using:

```
User-agent: Mail.Ru
Disallow: /
```

This should be okay to block if you do not want Russian traffic. Otherwise, mail.ru is said to follow robots.txt and I do not see any problems after doing a quick check of my database. It seems to be well behaved.

It will likely take a couple of days for mail.ru to read the robots.txt file and take notice of the change.

Push comes to shove, you can always use .htaccess (assuming Apache) to block access.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^.*\.mail\.ru$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^5\.61\.(2*3*[2-9]*)\.([0-2]*[0-5]*[0-5]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

But I would not do this too soon. It is likely not necessary.

Comment: @Inktown It should. I will take a bit of time for them to read the robots.txt file and notice the change. It is a well known search engine in Russia.

Comment: @Inktown Updated the answer with .htaccess code JIC.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using iptables to block the ips.

From the root linux shell I typed

```
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.13  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.12  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.10  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.11  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.14  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.15  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.16  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.17  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  217.69.133.18  -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s  fetcher9.mail.ru  -j DROP
```

And it stopped